# Agregar una tabla en wordpress con foreign key - ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, wordpress, datatable

Estoy tratando de agregar una tabla en la base de datos de wordpress que tenga como foreign key el id de wp_posts con el siguiente codigo

```
CREATE TABLE wp_post_ispremium(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    ispremium BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES wp_posts(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Al intentarlo obtengo el error:

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: la columna `id` de la tabla `wp_posts` es del mismo tipo de dato y longitud que la llave foránea que estás creando¿

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y muestranos como creaste la tabla wp_posts

Comment: Listo, era eso, la tabla padre tenia el parametro UNSIGNED y no lo estaba poniendo en mi codigo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Revertí tu edición, pues la solución no va en la misma pregunta, para eso tienes en la parte inferior la zona de respuestas